# How can I disable TypeScript preview?

Tags: web-essentials

Here's my context.

- I have a small screen at work
- Typescript preview screen does not remember its previous size and its annoying having to collapse it every time I open a TS file
- Web Essentials new version does not have TypeScript option where we can control any settings.

So, is there a way I can disable the preview screen?

Answer (score 6):

Tools->Options->Web Essentials->TypeScript
[image: Options dialog showing Web Essentials TypeScript pane, with Show preview pane highlighted]

Comment: Requires Visual studio restart or solution reopen.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent!

An option to disable the preview was added http://vswebessentials.com/changelog#cl_vs12_37